# Page freezes when creating component from props

Tags: reactjs

I am creating the Screens component in one file then passing it into the Modal component. Inside Modal I am trying to use Screens. Screens takes an index prop to tell it what to display. If I display props.screens (the Screens component) it works but I don't see a way to pass in props. If I try to display (screens) => () everything freezes.

File where Screens is defined...

```
const Screens = (props) => {
    let index = props !== undefined ? props.index.idx : 0;
    const [contentData, setContentData] = useState({});
    let [indexState, setIndexState] = useState(index);
    
    console.log(`indexState: ${indexState}`)
    
    const onChange = (e) => {
        const newData = {
          ...contentData,
          [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        }
        setContentData(newData)
    };
    
    const Screen1 = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <input type="text" id="screen1_input1" onChange={onChange} />
                <br />
                one
            </>
        )
    };
    const Screen2 = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <input type="text" id="screen2_input1" onChange={onChange} />
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="screen2_input2" onChange={onChange} />
                <br />
                two
            </>
        )
    };
    
    const content = [
        Screen1,
        Screen2
    ];
    
    return (
        <>
            <h2 className="screens">
                {content[indexState]()}
            </h2>
        </>
    );
}
```

This gets passed into  as props.screens.

Modal.js

```
...

const screens = props.screens;
const Screens = (screens) => (<Screens index={{idx:0}}/>);

...

return (
    {screens()} // works but doesn't let me pass in props
    {Screens} // everything freezes
)
```

Really I just need a way to use Screens in Modal in a way that lets me dynamically send it props.

Comment: The second freezes because you're just passing in a function to your render, but why are you passing it in as props at all? Is there a contextual reason why you can not import the component and use it normally?

Comment: @CoryHarper It's defined in a stories file for Storybook. This expects different test cases to be defined as varying props.

Comment: @CoryHarper Basically it's to keep the Modal component as generic as possible while letting it accept different Screens.

Comment: Okay, and one more thing, can you add to your original post how Modal is rendered?

Comment: @CoryHarper Modal is just a normal component on a page somewhere being passed props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways you could go about this, but here's just one:

```
// Modal.jsx
const Modal = ({ componentToRender }) => (
  ...JSX before component
  {componentToRender()}
  ..JSX after component
)

// File where Modal is being rendered
const SomeComponent = () => <Modal componentToRender={() => <Screen id={1} />} />
```

There's a very large number of other ways to implement this same exact thing, you're more or less implementing a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) by the way you describe Modal.

Your original implementation in the second instance would work just fine, but you need to call Screens to get the returned component from the function:

```
...

const Screens = (screens) => (<Screens index={{idx:0}}/>);

...

return (
    {Screens()}
)
```

Comment: That works if I import Screens into Modal, but not if I just try to use the one in props.screens...

Comment: If props.screens is just a functional component you can just render it like any other, `const Screens = props.screens .... return (<Screens {...someProps} />)`